# How do I make an iOS Map app use closest city as database parameter?

Tags: ios, mapkit

I have an app that fetches all data from the db and plots it on a map.  Currently it plots everything in my city.  So upon opening, it centers around my device location and plots all locations in the CoreData.  But the COreData has locations from various cities.

So currently the app centers around Miami and i can see the Miami locations.  If I were to drive to New York, it would center around me of course and plot those locations but it would also plot the Miami ones even though I would not see them on the map.

But if I want the user to be able to select a city he/she IS NOT currently in, and have the map center on THAT point and plot its locations, how do I get from the user selected city (a string) to the actual coordinate?

Comment: You mean select a city via a list created by you or on the map?

Answer (score 0):

You can use geocoder

Make an addressDictionary based on these keys -
City, Street, Country , ZIP, State - If you  only want city  make a dictionary like this

```
NSDictionary *addressDictionary = [[NSDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Miami",@"City", nil];
```

add CoreLocation.framework and import #import

use the following code to find the location -

```
CLGeocoder *geocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];
[geocoder geocodeAddressDictionary:addressDictionary completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {
  if([placemarks count]) {
    CLPlacemark *placemark = [placemarks objectAtIndex:0];
    CLLocation *location = placemark.location;
    CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate = location.coordinate;
    [self.googleMap animateToLocation:coordinate];
```